# VBA Excel create Outlook 2013 Appointment

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to create an Outlook Appointment with a Macro, I am having an issue with the code giving me an error of "Object Doesn't support this property or method" when it comes the Default Appointment Values. I have tried several fixes but am not experienced enough to resolve. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I am working with:

```
Sub CalendarInvite()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olAppItem As Object
    Dim r As Long

    Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")

    Dim mysub, myStart, myEnd

        mysub = Range("Title")
        myStart = Range("Date")
        myEnd = Range("Date")

        'creates a new appointment
        Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

        'set default appointment values
        With olAppItem
            .Location = Range("Location")
            .Body = Range("Body")
            .ReminderSet = True
            .BusyStatus = olFree
            .RequiredAttendees = "email@email.com"
            'saves the new appointment to the default folder
            .Save
        End With

    Set olAppItem = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is failing? Can you add a reference to the Outlook object model and work with early-bound objects instead? Coding against `Object` means all member call validations that normally happen at compile-time, get deferred to run-time - and when they fail they raise that runtime error 438. Always work with early-bound references if you can - you'll get better performance, and *IntelliSense*/autocomplete when writing your code, too.

Comment: Also `olFree` isn't defined anywhere (if it is, then you *have* a reference to the Outlook object model, which means you should have `olApp As Outlook.Application` instead of `Object`, and `olAppItem As WhateverTheActualTypeShouldBe`), which hints that you're probably not using `Option Explicit`. That will evaluate to `0` at run-time, and if that's not the underlying value for `olFree` (I'm not too familiar with the Outlook object model) then you're setting `.BusyStatus` to an undetermined value.

Comment: The .Location = Range("Location") is the first to fail, but i assume all of my appointment values will fail unless I define them differently. I assume I can change the .BusyStatus to equal True and that will resolve the olFree assignment.

Comment: Except `True` will set the `BusyStatus` to `-1`, and if you look at the Outlook object model (I just did) you'll see that `olFree` *is* defined as `0`, so you should either pass a literal `0`, or define `Const olFree As Long = 0`, or reference the object model and use the `OlBusyStatus.olFree` enum value. Setting it to `True` will probably just make things worse.

Comment: Okay so used Const olFree As Long = 0. I am still unsure what I need to do to fix the appointment values, can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
> ```

Assuming you're late-binding the Outlook library, the constant `olAppointmentItem` is not defined, so if you specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module the VBE will highlight if as undeclared.

I copied your code into `ThisWorkbook` in an empty workbook, and ran [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) code inspections (disclaimer: I manage that open-source project; it's completely free, and it's improving every day).

[image: code inspection results]

These results are particularly relevant to your problem:

```
Error: Option Explicit is not specified in 'ThisWorkbook' - (Book3) VBAProject.ThisWorkbook, line 1
Error: Variable 'olAppointmentItem' is used but not assigned - (Book3) VBAProject.ThisWorkbook, line 16
Error: Variable 'olFree' is used but not assigned - (Book3) VBAProject.ThisWorkbook, line 23
Error: Local variable 'olAppointmentItem' is not declared - (Book3) VBAProject.ThisWorkbook, line 16
Error: Local variable 'olFree' is not declared - (Book3) VBAProject.ThisWorkbook, line 23
```

The underlying value of `olFree` in the Outlook library is `0`, so that's not a *big* deal as far as run-time errors are concerned.

However `olAppointmentItem` not being defined *is* pretty big: you think you're working against an `AppointmentItem` object, but because the underlying value of `olAppointmentItem` in the Outlook library is `1` and you're providing a `0`, the runtime type of `olAppItem` is actually a `MailItem`.

And because a `MailItem` doesn't have a `Location` property, attempting to set it will raise that run-time error 438 you're getting - "object doesn't support this property or method".

Therefore, you should be creating the `olAppItem` like this:

```
Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(1)
```

Or, define the `olAppointmentItem` constant:

```
Const olAppointmentItem As Long = 1
Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

Or, reference the Outlook object model (*Tools > References...*), replace `As Object` with the actual types you want to be using (`olApp As Outlook.Application`, `olAppItem As AppointmentItem`), and then the `olAppointmentItem` and `olFree` constants will be taken from the Outlook library.

I'll skip the other inspection results because they're not relevant to that specific question, but you'll notice a number of dead variables there.

Comment: I guess I will keep digging around, I do not think I understand what the fix is. Thank you for your attempt to help

Comment: @RichardG `olAppointmentItem` does not exist, it means nothing unless you reference the Outlook library. Because you're not using `Option Explicit`, VBA allows that undeclared local variable to exist, and initializes it with a value of `0`. So you're doing `Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)`, which creates a new `MailItem` object. You want to be doing `Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(1)` to create an `AppointmentItem` object. You should only use late-binding when you have a real good reason to do so, and you should always specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. It actually created the appointment. Now I just have to figure out how to make it go on the right date and time. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: @RichardG I can't stress how much easier your life would be if you simply referenced the Outlook type library and worked with an `AppointmentItem` object instead of an `Object`. If you stick to late-binding, you'll need to refer to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862177.aspx) to figure out what members to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an appointment in Outlook, using Excel, run the script below.

```
Private Sub Add_Appointments_To_Outlook_Calendar()

    'Include Microsoft Outlook nn.nn Object Library from Tools -> References
    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim Remind_Time As Double

    i = 2
    Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)

    'Loop through entire list of Reminders to be added
    While Subj <> ""
        Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

        oAppt.Subject = Subj
        oAppt.Location = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        oAppt.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Remind_Time = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4) * 1 * 60
        oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Remind_Time
        oAppt.AllDayEvent = True
        oAppt.Save

        i = i + 1
        Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    Wend
    MsgBox "Reminder(s) Added To Outlook Calendar"

End Sub
```

[image]

' The code comes from this link:
http://officetricks.com/add-appointment-to-outlook-calendar-through-excel-macro-vba/

The script is run from Excel, and as such, you must set a reference to Outlook before you run the code.  Also, notice that the worksheet needs to be setup properly for the script to run.  It should look something like this.  Everything is read from Excel into Outlook.

Comment: Thanks ASH. I found your post and link both helpful.